# Django form Datetime field valid error after add django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'

Tags: django, forms

I use django version 1.10, When a add LocaleMiddleware into settings.py, form valid error

Here is my model and form

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...   
    is_first_login = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_expired = models.DateTimeField(default=date_expired_default, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Date expired')
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
```

```
class UserAddForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username', 'name', 'email', 'groups', 'wechat',
            'phone', 'enable_otp', 'role', 'date_expired', 'comment',
        ]

        help_texts = {
            'username': '* required',
            'email': '* required',
        }
```

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: I seen the form data have no difference

Comment: What error does the form give?

Comment: <ul class="errorlist"><li>date_expired<ul class="errorlist"><li>Input a valid date/datetime </li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: The origin message is <ul class="errorlist"><li>date_expired<ul class="errorlist"><li>输入一个有效的日期/时间。</li></ul></li></ul>

Answer (score 0):

Resolved 
If not add Locale Middleware, date format mm/dd/yyyy is valid else invalid

So I custom datetime field in template {{ form.date_expired.value|date:'Y-m-d' }}

Ok, success